# Get shortest possible groups in a string using regex

Tags: java, regex

I have a long string where I need to find all the shortest groups. Currently what is happening is I'm getting 2 groups, one of which contains all the data in between(it could have been more specific as required). I'm not able to understand what should I change in the regex pattern to handle my case.

**String** - `"aaa START1 value1 /END bbb START2 value2 /END TAG ccc START3 value3 /END TAG ddd"`

**Expected** - `START2 value2 /END TAG , START3 value3 /END TAG`
**Actual** -  `START1 value1 /END bbb START2 value2 /END TAG , START3 value3 /END TAG`

My class is -

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Reg {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String response = "aaa START1 value1 /END bbb START2 value2 /END TAG ccc START3 value3 /END TAG ddd";

        StringBuilder sb1 = new StringBuilder();

        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("START[0-9]+(.*?)/END TAG");
        Matcher matcher1 = p.matcher(response);

        while (matcher1.find()) {

            sb1.append(matcher1.group()).append(" , ");
        }
        System.out.println(sb1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
START[0-9]+(?:(?!\\bSTART).)*?/END TAG
```

You can try this.See demo.The `lookahead` will not allow another `START` in between your groups.

https://regex101.com/r/cJ6zQ3/21

Comment: Thanks a lot. It is working.  Could you please help me understand what exactly is happening with this - `(?:(?!\\bSTART).)*?` ?

Comment: See [Tempered Greedy Token Solution](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html#tempered_greed). The `?` is redundant here at `*?`.

Comment: @stribizhev, I tried after removing `*?`, it didn't return anything.

Comment: @stribizhev, you are correct. My mistake. I removed `*?` from there. And thanks for the link. I will go through it.

Comment: @AbhashUpadhyaya you just need to remove `*?` and put `*` instead