# Get more specific shortest possible group in a string using regex

Tags: java, regex

Recently I've asked a question which was answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32985926/get-shortest-possible-groups-in-a-string-using-regex) but new scenario was added to the requirements.

**String** - `"aaa START1 value1 /END bbb START2 value2_1 /END TAG value2_2 /END TAG ccc START3 value3 /END TAG ddd"`

**Expected** - `START2 value2_1 /END TAG value2_2 /END TAG , START3 value3 /END TAG`
**Actual** -  `START2 value2_1 /END TAG , START3 value3 /END TAG`

Comment: How can your expected match include a `START3` in match but skip first `START1` at the same time?

Answer (score 0):

To match longest string make it non-greedy:

```
\bSTART[0-9]+(?:(?!\bSTART).)*/END TAG\b
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/bQ5mK5/2)